# Why is $K^{\ast n}$ contained in the norm group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

http://www.bprim.org/cyclotomicfieldbook/rlmain.pdf

In section 5, $K$ is a local $p$-adic field containing the $n$th roots of unity, and $L = K(\sqrt[n]{x} : x \in K^{\ast})$.  Kummer theory tells us that $[L : K] = [K^{\ast} : K^{\ast n}]$, and local class field theory tells us that $[L : K] = [K^{\ast} : N_{L/K}(L^{\ast})]$.  The author concludes that $N_{L/K}(L^{\ast}) = K^{\ast n}$, but I don't see how one of these things is contained in the other.  Why are $n$th powers norms from $L$, for example?

Comment: $L$ is not a finite extension of $K$ if you take all $x\in K$ in the definition of $L$, so you can't have $[L:K]=[K^*:K^{*n}]$ and the other equality.  So I don't think you can prove $K^{*n}$ is contained in the norm group in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple actually.  By Kummer theory, the Galois group of $L$ over $K$ has exponent $n$, so if $x^n \in K^{\ast n}$, we have $$(x^n, L/K) = (x, L/K)^n = 1$$ where $(-,L/K)$ is the local Artin map.  Thus $x^n$ is in the kernel of the Artin map, i.e. it is a norm from $L$.